# How to patch a reactive form with multi nested json values

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using the value of a multi nested (Infinity level) reactive form which contains formArray, formGroups and formControls. Which is stored in DB.

Currently, I am patching the form using a recursion function that loops through the entire JSON and makes formArrays, formGroups and formControls based on keys and values.

Now the issue is, this method which I am using is not good as per performance perspective, so is there any better way to patch this kind of multi nested form in one go? (Just create form, no need to show in HTML)

This is simplified JSON for question reference -

Any section can have subSections and then subSections can have some kind of section

```
const formDataSections = [
  {
    index: 1,
    sectionName: "",
    subSections: [
      {
        index: 1,
        subSectionName: "",
        sections: [
          {
            index: null,
            sectionName: "",
            subSections: [
              {
                index: null,
                subSectionName: "",
                sections: [
                  {
                    index: null,
                    sectionName: "",
                  },
                  {
                    index: null,
                    sectionName: "",
                    subSections: [
                      {
                        index: null,
                        subSectionName: "",
                        sections: [
                          {
                            index: null,
                            sectionName: "",
                          },
                          {
                            index: null,
                            sectionName: "",
                            subSections: [],
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            index: null,
            sectionName: "",
            subSections: [
              {
                index: null,
                contentTypes: [],
                sections: [
                  {
                    index: null,
                    sectionName: "",
                    subSections: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: If it goes to infinity I think the only way to do it is recursion

Comment: This Article probably can help you with your problem https://www.py4u.net/discuss/331868

Comment: > Now the issue is, this method which I am using is not good as per performance perspective, so is there any better way to patch this kind of multi nested form in one go?

The method you are using is probably not the issue; the algorithm you are using is unbounded and so runtime is indeterminate. Can you be more specific about what your problem is with the performance? (How long does it take/What is acceptable?)

You would need to share your input - the rules or data you have that lead to the construction of the data - for anyone to consider an alternative approach. Recursion is all I see.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a custom "subform" component using `ControlValueAccessor` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)) and call the component recursively ([example](https://medium.com/@sakshisubedi/recursive-component-in-angular-a229d871a006))

I don't think you can avoid recursion since the list has potentially infinite length

Here's a (*not fully working...*) [StackBlitz example](https://angular-ivy-gdvbrx.stackblitz.io), just to showcase what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am already using component recursion to create this form (as suggested by you). Now I need a solution to patch the value in a form (this time I don't need to show it in html), I just need a full form in ts file only. And my expectation is, patch the complete form in just one go, without using recursion function. I need a form, just log it in console, I am happy :) Thank you.

Comment: You can patch the top level form and the values will be passed in the nested forms also